# using awk to modify multiple columns

Tags: linux, awk, command-line

I have a csv file with two columns: date string in ISO8601 and a linux timestamp.  How do I use `awk` to get the output in the following format: col-1: original ISO; col-2: convert timestamp (2) to ISO8601; col-3: diff between the two times (say, in ms)

Example:

**Input**:

```
  2018-01-09T16:55:22.545+0000,1515508979185
```

**Output**:

```
  2018-01-09T16:55:22.545+0000,2018-01-09T14:42:59.185+0000,36743360
```

Comment: Not clear, please post more clear requirements of your question with more suitable examples in your post.

Comment: I'm not sure what is not clear about calculating a difference between two dates and normalizing them to the same ISO 8601 format.  Could you be more specific about what is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gawk** has all the necessary functions to convert date and time between different formats. This is a Gawk extension.

Consider the following command

```
awk -F, '{ patsplit($1,a,"[0-9]*");
      time1 = mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",
                   a[1], a[2] ,a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6]))*1000 + a[7];
      time2 = mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d %H %M %S",$2/1000,a[8]))*1000 +$2 %1000;  
      isodate2 = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",$2/1000,a[8]);
      printf "%s;%s.%03d;%s\n",
             $1,
             isodate2,$2 % 1000,
             time1 - time2}' csvfile
```

It would produce

```
2018-01-09T16:55:22.545+0000;2018-01-09T14:42:59.185;7943360
```

### Explanation

We use `,` as a field separator as the input is a CSV file.
First we parse the 1st column argument which is an ISO 8601 date. We use `patsplit()` to extract all numbers out of an ISO 8601 string into an array `a` so that

```
  a[1] = YYYY, a[2] = mm, a[3] = dd, 
  a[4] = HH, a[5] = MM, a[6] = SS, a[7] = uuu
```

We use the array `a` to convert the 1st column date into a timestamp and compute the difference in microseconds and store the result in the `time1` variable.

Handling timezones here requires to compute the equivalent of the 2nd time in the timezone of the 1st timestamp.

Then we print the output line starting with the 1st column; using `strftime` to convert the timestamp from the 2nd column into ISO8601 date and printing the microseconds separately.

The difference between time1 and time2 is not the same as in the original post.

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-only for time functions.

Answer (score 1):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
     { 
         cmd1 = "date -d"$1" +%s"; 
         cmd2 = "date -d@"int($2/1000)" +%FT%T.%3N%z";
         cmd1 | getline d1; close(cmd1);
         cmd2 | getline d2; close(cmd2);
         print $1, d2, d1*1000 - $2 
     }' file
```